# Django app works fine locally, but fails in heroku when logging into admin sit

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, django-rest-framework

[image: screenshot of the problem]

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
#email=models.EmailField(max_length=40,unique=True)
phone=models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True,)
name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
is_volunteer=models.BooleanField()
district=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
areaofvol=models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
address=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
lat=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=6)
lon=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=6)
is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True,null=True)

REQUIRED_FIELDS=['lat','lon','is_volunteer']

USERNAME_FIELD ='phone'

objects=UserProfileManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

The app works locally and I also checked the db.sqlite3 file in heroku bash it had is_staff inside flood_userprofile.

Comment: seems like you forgot to apply the migrations

Comment: no I did python3 manage.py  migrate --run-syncdb. It shows the column inside db.sqlite3 file

Comment: If this is your error most probably the issue is in your settings, please share it's code might help to understand the issue

Answer (score 1):

This works with PostgreSQL and Heroku and always worked for me:

```
delete all database
python manage.py makemigrations
git add  -A
git commit -m "Databases"
git push heroku master
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```